# Pruning a general tree using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a neo4j database containing vertices which are either of type folder or leaf. A general tree is modelled using :childof relations, and there is a single 'root' node which is the common ancestor for all vertices.

When presenting the tree, I want to filter out either full branches based on the id of any vertex of type folder. Additionally there is a filter for any properties on vertices of type leaf. The tricky part is that I do not want to see any folders where all descendant leaf nodes are filtered out. Each query only returns immediate descendants, but the filter is applied to the whole subtree. The query must return the immediate children, and a collection of the id of each folder containing leafs which are not filtered out.

The use case is an API for showing a hierarchy based on some filter constraints. I have programmed this in the API application code, but transferring all data from the db to the API application is too slow, so I need to improve the query to condense the data transfer. A third approach is using a purpose built process that does this filtering, keeping the tree in memory. This has been done with some success, but I prefer to use shelf-ware if I can.

The following code is used to get the top level nodes, without filtering. I struggle with expressing MATCH only if at least one descendant also matches

```
MATCH (p)-[:childof]->(s:Folder) WHERE s.name = 'root'
WITH p OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[:childof*1..]->(p)
WHERE NOT((v)<-[:childof]-(:Folder))
RETURN p, collect(v.id) as folder_ids
```

My personal inclination to the problem is that it is too specific for a general purpose graph engine, but I am hoping to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're close.

We can use pattern comprehensions at the folder level to check for children that meet the filter, and make sure we only keep folders that have at least one child that meets the filter criteria.

And at the immediate descendent level, if we use a MATCH instead of an OPTIONAL MATCH, since folders will get filtered for you, the only immediate descendants that are left are ones with at least one of these folders.

Let's say for example that our filter is that leaf nodes must have `active = true`, so we want to make sure that our folders for consideration must have at least one child node meeting the filter, and when we get back to the immediate descendants, we only want to keep that descendent if the collection of eligible folders isn't empty.

Something like this:

```
MATCH (p)-[:childof]->(s:Folder) WHERE s.name = 'root'
WITH p 
MATCH (folder)-[:childof*1..]->(p)
WHERE NOT((folder)<-[:childof]-(:Folder)) AND 
  size([(folder)<-[:childof]-(child) WHERE child.active = true | child]) <> 0
RETURN p, collect(folder.id) as folder_ids
```

Comment: This works! Now, for adding pruning of whole branches, I could only manage to implement it by capturing the relationships on the second match statement like `MATCH rels=...`, and adding a `WHERE any(x in nodes(rels) where x.id in [<list of ids to explore>]`, but this is quite slow as it still traverses the whole subtree. Is there any way to prevent that?